# How can I install SQLite to be used with OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice.org, database, sqlite

My GPS uses a SQLite database. I would like to access this data using OpenOffice to look at the relationship between data entries.  Is there a way to install SQLite with OpenOffice?

Comment: There has been discussion about supporting SQLite as LibreOffice Base's native backend (instead of HSQL). Not sure whether this went anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think OpenOffice.org should be able to use the `libsqliteodbc` [image: Install libsqliteodbc] ODBC driver, but I have never tried it.

---

**Edit**

Okay, I tested it and will explain how to do it...

If you click the icon above to install `libsqliteodbc`, make sure that you also install the AddOn “Graphical tools for ODBC management and browsing (unixodbc-bin)” (so, make sure the checkbox is ticked).

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to launch the Run application dialog window and run `ODBCConfig`.  In the first tab "User DSN", press the "Add..." button.

[image: screenshot ODBC Data Source Administrator]

You will get a "Select a driver..." dialog.  Select the SQLite (version 2) or SQLite3 (version 3) driver as appropriate, then press the "Ok" button.

[image: screenshot Select a driver...]

Now you can set up the properties for the actual ODBC Data Source.  Fill in the Name field (use whatever descriptive name you want, it's there for your convenience).  Fill in the Database field (use the small `>` button to browse & select it).  Leave all the other fields alone.  Press the [image: checkmark button screenshot] button to save this Data Source.

[image: screenshot Data Source Properties]

After this you should see your new Data Source in the ODBC Data Source Administrator and in OpenOffice.org.

In OpenOffice.org select the option to connect to an existing database, select ODBC from the drop-down, then press "Next".  Now you should be able to select your newly-created ODBC source when you press the "Browse" button...

Comment: This is wonderful.  I have been using the previous links for days trying to do this and you were able to fix it in a few hours.  Thank you so much!

Comment: In (K)ubuntu precise `ODBCConfig` is not available. Use `ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4` instead. Basically the same.. looks just a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/) extension for Firefox to open the database and export it as CSV,SQL or XML. I'm sure you will be able to import one of those formats into OpenOffice. However, the extension itself is enough to view and manage data inside the database. There is no need to import to OO.

[image]

If you don't want to use Firefox for that, then use a standalone application:

## [sqlitebrowser](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sqlitebrowser) [image: Install sqlitebrowser]

Comment: that's a cool extension, gonna look it up now you mention it =D

Comment: @Roland Taylor I can't live without it :)

Comment: just installed it =D

Comment: @Roland Taylor you can launch it on a new widow or new tab.

Comment: +1 useful answer, I use this extension frequently myself, my second choice is Sqliteman.