# Get a SQLite3 db in LibreOffice (via ODBC). Using Ubuntu 11.04 (64bit)

Tags: libreoffice, database, sqlite

I'm stuck with this. I had SQLite working with OpenOffice in the past. But since then i reinstalled my machine and so... Now I can't get it to work.

i pretty much followed this guide: http://documentation.openoffice.org/HOW_TO/data_source/SQLite.pdf

Except that I changed (with sudo ODBCConfig) the SQLite drivers config to:

```
Driver: /usr/lib/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so 
Driver64: /usr/lib64/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so 
Setup: /usr/lib/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so 
Setup64: /usr/lib64/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so
```

(Those files exist on my system)

I also added my database under the User DSN tab.

When I start LibreOffice Base and browse for a ODBC DataSource it turns up empty. I guess this isn't easy to answer without having access to my system. But maybe anyone has an idea? Or some way to debug the connection that I'm not aware of?

Here are some info about my packages:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep odbc
libodbcinstq1c2             install
libsqliteodbc               install
odbcinst                    install
odbcinst1debian2                install
unixodbc                    install
unixodbc-bin                install

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep sqlite
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3         install
libmono-sqlite1.0-cil           install
libmono-sqlite2.0-cil           install
libqt4-sql-sqlite               install
libsqlite0                  install
libsqlite3-0                install
libsqliteodbc               install
sqlite3                 install
sqlitebrowser               install
sqliteman                   install
sqliteman-doc               install
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem was pretty obvious. I used the command: `sudo ODBCConfig` to configure the driver (which the odbcsqlite package really seemed to have done for me already).

Anyway, without restarting ODBCConfig as local user I configured the database under the User DSN tab. As I would expect, if I've just used my brain a little more, the database would then only be shown to user root (I never verified this, but it seems obvious).

My solution was to restart ODBCConfig as the local user (i. e. without sudo) and then add the database. Then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Please, take a look at this question, there are some tips on how to use SQLite on Ubuntu:

[How can I install SQLite to be used with OpenOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10635/how-can-i-install-sqlite-to-be-used-with-openoffice)

And here is the official Openoffice guide on using SQLite:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_SQLite_With_OpenOffice.org

This is related to Openoffice, but should work also with Libreoffice.

Comment: Found it just after posting the question. I take a look at it after lunch an report how it goes :) Thnx!

Comment: I got the solution by myself but you got an upvote for the link. I share my solution soon...

Comment: Glad to know you found the solution.. :)